# How do I access my files saved onto my express server?

Tags: javascript, express

Currently, I can 'upload' my images onto my server with Multer but now, how can I serve that file? If I visit the path which is: `http://localhost:3001/public/backend/public/uploads/user-admin-1556247519876.PNG`, i get a 404 cannot get.

I feel like i'm just missing a single step but I can't spot my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the **express.static** built-in middleware function in Express.

For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

Comment: Thats the thing though, I do have that. `app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'public' ) ) )` When I visit the route: `http://localhost:3001/public/uploads/user-testuser-1556247519876.PNG`, I get the 404...

Comment: If you mentioned public as your static directory, then don't use the directory name again in url. you just visit http://localhost:3001/uploads/user-testuser-1556247519876.PNG